# Ordering a table that was created from a factor variable in r

Tags: r, sorting, datatables

Okay, so I have a data frame, df,  with one column: artist name.

```
        artist_name
1       Linkin Park
2         Lady Gaga
3        Pink Floyd
4       Linkin Park
5         Lady Gaga
6         Lady Gaga
```

Artist name is a factor variable, and to see how many times each artist appears in this data frame, I would say:

table (df$artist_name)

The only problem is that in my project, I have 17,000s rows (and thousands of artists), and I only want to see the artists with the most appearances in the table. Because there are so many different artists, I am unable to find the most frequent artist names. I know that if I have a data frame, I can use the order () function, but is there any way to sort a table? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

We can `sort` the `table` output in descending order, extract the `names` of the first element

```
names(sort(table(df$artist_name), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
```

If we need more than one, just change the number in the index to a range

```
names(sort(table(df$artist_name), decreasing = TRUE)[1:5])
```

NOTE: No packages needed

Answer (score 0):

We can use `count` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(artist_name, sort = TRUE) %>% slice(1:10)
```

Or using `top_n` :

```
df %>% count(artist_name) %>% top_n(10, n)
```

This will return top 10 artists, replace 10 with whatever number you want.